# Crete list of words from text file

Tags: python, file

**Questions** Create a list called emotions that contains the first word of every line in emotion_words.txt.

```
emotions=[]  
with open("emotion_words.txt","r+") as f:    
    for line in f:    
       emotions.append(line.strip()[0])
```

**Any Suggestions** on where I have gone wrong... I know it has something to do with that last line

Comment: just add `file_contents = f.read().splitlines()` or `f.readlines()` before `for line in f:` and then change `for line in f:` to `for line in file_contents:` and then for getting the first word, may you please provide us with an example of how the file looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments you need to `read` the content of the file and then split the sentence using the `split` method of `strings` like this:

```py
emotions=[]
with open("emotion_words.txt","r+") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
       emotions.append(line.split()[0].strip())
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean

```
emotions.append(line.split()[0].strip())
```

otherwise you're saving the first letter of each line, not the first word.